# Is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in the field $\mathbb Q_5$ a number field?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

> Is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in the field $\mathbb Q_5$ of $5$-adic numbers a number field, if yes what is the degree ?

To be honest I don't understand the question, what does it mean to be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in the field $\mathbb Q_5$? Maybe $\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb Q_5$ ?

on Wikipedia I saw also;

''The algebraic closure of a field $K$ has the same cardinality as $K$ if $K$ is infinite, and is countably infinite if $K$ is finite.''

Therefore If $\mathbb Q$ is not entirely contained in $\mathbb Q_5$, $\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb Q_5$ cannot be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$, is that correct ?

Comment: If $K \hookrightarrow L$ is any field extension, the algebraic closure of $K$ in $L$ is defined to be the set of all elements of $L$ that are algebraic over $K$ (i.e. satisfy a polynomial equation with coefficients in $K$). Apply this definition to the field extension $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}_5$.

Comment: @c_c_chaos OK so the set is not $\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb Q_5$. But I have difficulties to visualize how $\mathbb Q_5$  looks like, is it already a number field ? Then it is sufficient to show that the intermediate set you described is a field, am I wrong ?

Comment: @inequal: $\mathbb{Q}_5$ is uncountable so it must be infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$ and it can't be a number field. Exercise 6 on p. 496 of Lang's Algebra (you'll find it on Google books if you don't have the book to hand) asks the reader to prove that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ contains infinitely many quadratic fields of type $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-m})$. This implies that the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_5$ is not a number field. I am afraid I don't know the solution to this exercise.

Comment: @inequal It is difficult to visualize $\mathbb{Q}_5$: It is a [totally disconnected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space). This distinguishes $\mathbb{Q}_5$ from $\mathbb{R}$ but keep in mind that, on the other hand, $\mathbb{R}$ and all the $\mathbb{Q}_p$ share one property as well: They arise as completions of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to one of its valuations. When you internalize this and think through some of the properties of such completions you won't ever again ask yourself whether $\mathbb{Q}_5$ is a number field, not even for one moment.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, to address your concern about being an algebraic closure in an extension, you are correct, $\overline{\Bbb Q}\cap\Bbb Q_5\subseteq\overline{\Bbb Q}_5$ is exactly the set you are looking for.

To see that we are not dealing with a number field, we appeal to the theory of quadratic extensions of $\Bbb Q$. Since $\Bbb Q_5$ is a completion at an odd prime, we know by Hensel's lemma and quadratic reciprocity that for any prime $q\equiv 1\mod 5$ we have that $\sqrt{q}\in\Bbb Q_5$ since

> $$\left({q\over 5}\right)=\left({1\over 5}\right)=1.$$

Then Dirichlet's theorem on infinitely many primes in arithmetic progressions implies there are infinitely many distinct primes $q_1,q_2,\ldots $ so that $q_i=5k+1$. Hence $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{q_i})\subseteq \Bbb Q_5$. But then the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb Q_5$ contains the infinite dimensional extension $\Bbb Q(q_1,q_2,\ldots)$, hence cannot be a number field, since--by definition--number fields are finite, algebraic extensions of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I know neither Hensel's lemma nor Dirichlet's theorem  but briefly said $\mathbb Q_5$ is not a finite extension, thanks for the answer

Comment: Hensel’s Lemma is deep and important, but not hard; if you want to understand $\Bbb Q_p$, you need to know it.

Comment: @inequal as Professor Lubin says, Hensel's lemma is indispensable. It is the tool by which one usually decides if a polynomial has a root in $\Bbb Q_p$, in this problem it's exactly finding a bunch of distinct polynomials with roots that is necessary to prove infinite dimensionality. Dirichlet's theorem is a classical result, and the case I'm quoting can be proven by looking at cyclotomic extensions of $\Bbb Q$ and prime behavior there if you know about those or via calculus with $L$-functions. See for example Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory* for the former.

Answer (score 4):

As if the excellent answers of Adam Hughes and @benh weren’t enough, I’ll give another argument something like that of Adam, but not using Hensel.

For simplicity, let’s take $p\ne2$. Look at the Binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{1/2}=1+\frac12x- \frac18x^2 + +\frac1{16}x^3 - \frac5{128}x^4 +\cdots\>$. You’ll notice that the only denominators are powers of $2$, which are “units” in $\Bbb Q_p$, that is, $|2|_p=1$, so the denominators have nothing to do with the size of the coefficient. The numerators, whatever they are, are ordinary integers, so their $p$-adic absolute values are all $\le1$. Now, if for $x$ you substitute something that’s small, like $pm$ for any integer $m$, you get a Cauchy series out of $(1+x)^{1/2}$, so that the square root of $1+pm$ will always be in $\Bbb Q_p$.

Two remarks and I’ll quit. First, if $q$ is a prime, the series $(1+x)^{1/q}$ has only powers of $q$ in its denominators, so for any $p\ne q$, you’ll have $q$-th roots of $1+pm$. So in $\Bbb Q_2$, you have lots of cube roots of integers. Second, you can also show that $(1+4x)^{1/2}$ has ordinary everyday integers for coefficients, so that can give you what you want also, for $\Bbb Q_2$.

Answer (score 2):

I think Adam Hughes gave a great answer to your initial question. Let me try to say a bit more about what the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_5$ is using algebraic number theory.

Let $p$ be any prime, then we can embed $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$. The algebraic closure $N$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is then the largest subextension $\mathbb{Q}_p|N|\mathbb{Q}$ that is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. If we fix an algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, this must contain an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and we can say $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$. So algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ give rise to algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ (or rather of $N$). But we can go the other way round:

Let $K|\mathbb{Q}$ be any number field and choose a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of the ring of integers of $K$ over $p$. Then the completion of $K$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ will be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Different primes may produce different extensions, but if $K$ is a Galois number field, those will be isomorphic.

More precisely, if $K|\mathbb{Q}$ has Galois group $G$, then the corresponding extension $K_\mathfrak{p}|\mathbb{Q}_p$ will be Galois and its Galois group can be identified with the decomposition group of $\mathfrak{p}$, that is $D_\mathfrak{p} = \{\sigma \in G| \sigma \mathfrak{p}  = \mathfrak{p}\}$. In the limit, we can therefore identify $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p|\mathbb{Q}_p)$ with the decomposition group of a prime of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ (the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$). So the choice of an algebraic closure in the beginning was actually a choice of a prime $\mathfrak{P}\subseteq \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$.

A bit of work shows that if $e(\mathfrak{p}|p)$ is the ramification index and $f(\mathfrak{p}|p)$ is the residue degree, then:
$$[K_\mathfrak{p}:\mathbb{Q}_p] = e(\mathfrak{p}|p)f(\mathfrak{p}|p).$$

So we can give an explicit description of $N$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$: It is the compositum of all number fields $K$ in which the prime lying under $\mathfrak{P}$ has trivial ramification index and residue degree in $K|\mathbb{Q}$

> In particular, $N$ contains all number fields in which $p$ is
>   completely split.

As Adam Hughes pointed out much more straightforward then I did, this includes all quadratic extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})|\mathbb{Q}$ for which $d\equiv \pm 1 \bmod 5$, and $N$ cannot be a number field.